# Android IoT Hub Illegal Charset Name

Tags: android, azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm working with Microsoft Azure SDK. I'm trying to register a device using the tutorial at the [LINK HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-java-java-getstarted#create-a-device-identity).
During this procedure a token should be generated but I've got this exception

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eu.beamdigital.beamwatch/eu.beamdigital.beamwatch.SplashActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: java.nio.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2583)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

This exception is issued by this line

```
targetUri = URLEncoder.encode(this.resourceUri.toLowerCase(), String.valueOf(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

which is part of the IoT Hub Service SDK.
How can I fix this?

My Environment

- Android Studio 3.1.2
- Android API 23 (I'm forced to use this)
- Android Marshmallow
- Azure device client: com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot:iot-device-client:1.9.+
- Java 1.8.0_172

Comment: What's your JDK version?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT added

Comment: The exception is issued by this line: `RegistryManager.createFromConnectionString(connectionString)` in [the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-java-java-getstarted#create-a-device-identity)? How do you get the iot hub connection string and what's its format?

Comment: @GenerosoCarbone Were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: @DevAndroid first of all, I've made a mistake in the description. I was using the iot-device-client not the iot-service-client (I was trying to send data to the iot-hub). Second, I've updated the sdk and then avoid any strange  kind of charset conversion of the connection string.